# Why the General Lomb-Scargle results are doubled?

Tags: fourier-transform, power, signal-processing

I got a problem when computing the GLS on MATLAB for my master deegree thesis.
I need to do a comparison between the PSD and amplitude spectrum of a signal computed with three different metods, the second and thirt being necessary because my data are not sampled evenly. The first metod is the FFT. No problem, MATLAB does it easily and it is a standard, the second is the Lomb-Scargle periodogram. Here i keep the not normalized output for comparison with the FFT. To match the "zeroing out" of the DC component in the LS, i subtracted the mean of the data from the data themself before doing the FFT (so i computed the FFt of the zero mean signal). To compute the amplitude from LS, i computed the square root of the PSD*f, f being the frequency.
The results are very close in magnitude but the amplitude spectra is very different in shape.
Lastly is [the General LS](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2573). I used the code for MATLAB provided by the metod's proposer here:https://github.com/mzechmeister/GLS/tree/master/matlab. I needed to tweak the code a little in the beginning 'cause the way he compute the frequency gives only negative results. Anyway, i removed the normalizations and computed the pure PSD, then took back the power and computed the amplitude as its square root.
Now, the amplitude plot is fine but the PSD one has the magnitude boubled. I though it was like this because the LS in his definition has a 0.5 factor, and assuming the GLS should have it as well i divided the PSD magnitude by 2, but now the amplitude spectra is a bit off while the PSD is perfect.

The question is: i'm doing something wrong or i'm missing something? Normally i wouldn't care too much about the amplitudes, but for this study they are important, so if they are too different depending on the metod i should say why. Are the Power and Amplitude simply one the square root of the other or there's something alse, maybe a coefficent i'm missing? I even though the PSD was doubled by coincidence, and that was the right results, but i wouldn't know how to justify it.
I'll leave two pictures for reference.

[image: PSD before and after the 0.5 moltiplication, wih LS and GLS]

[image: Amplitude before and after the 0.5 moltiplication, wih LS and GLS]

Comment: Welcome to SE. This question looks more like a scientific computing question, not a physics question. Perhaps you'll have better luck on the [Computing science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi, and thanks. 
Actually the question is more about the relation between power and amplitude and the analisys in the frequency domain, so i though this was the right place.
I added a lot of detail on the method and the tools i used to help find an error, but is more about the physics of the problem.
In any case, if it is the wrong section, i'll try on the Computing Science. Thank for the answer!